# Which organs in the body are responsible for measuring temperature?

Tags: physiology, temperature

As an instrumentation engineer, I have designed temperature control systems
capable of measuring and controlling temperature with a precision of 0.001K over a
wide temperature range.  I have always wondered how the human body maintains its
temperature within a fraction of a degree; specifically, where and how is the 
temperature measurement done?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoregulation#In_humans

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoreceptor

Comment: As @inf3rno said there are thermoreceptors (TRPV ion channels) that are responsive to temperature. They are involved in temperature sensation of the environment as well as the body itself. I am not fully sure if they are the sole temperature sensors of the body. Have a look at these articles: [[1](http://www.nature.com/nrn/journal/v4/n7/abs/nrn1141.html)], [[2](http://www.cell.com/trends/endocrinology-metabolism/abstract/S1043-2760%2813%2900108-2)] and [[3](http://www.molecularpain.com/content/8/1/36)]

Answer (score 1):

#### Human thermo detection comes from a protein, expressed in high levels in the nervous system.

As per comments, there are a group of transmembrane proteins called transient receptor potential cation channel subfamily V (TRPV) ion channels that can detect temperature *changes*. Although the exact mechanism of the protein remains unclear, [a study published in Nature 2010](http://www.nature.com/neuro/journal/v13/n6/full/nn.2552.html) showed that a protein called TRPV1 opens and closes to allow increased or decreased sensitivity to temperature change.

There is no specific organ that is responsible for temperature detection, however TRPV1 is [expressed in high levels in the nervous system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRPV1#Central_nervous_system).